# Keeping a single record for groups in sql table

Tags: sql

I have a table for the "Features and benefits" of a list of products. In this table there is an item number, base part number, and three benefit columns. I want to change this to a dynamic table in which they can have any number of benefits, which I can do easily. The problem is the features and benefits do not change between items under the same base part number. For example under the base part "708" the items 708/s, 708/m and 708/l would all have the same features and benefits, so I want to get rid of the redundancy by removing the item column and just have a single entry for each distinct base part number. How would I go about this?

Comment: Please show us the relevant table schema, sample input data and expected output. In addition, what database product and version?

Answer (score 0):

You might need to introduce a 'benefits grouper' field in your table, and relate that to another table with benefitsGrouperID, benefitSequence, and benefit

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, due to a lack of time (and sql skill...) I just went ahead and wrote a little application to do it for me. I should have just done that in the first place, stick with your strengths right ;)